# How to stop django from giving html pages as errors

Tags: django

I am working on an application with some friends and the back end REST API is in django. I sometimes get huge blocks of html printed to the console in place of anything meaningful, when I call an API from my angular front end. I have done some googling and I can't seem to find an answer of how to turn this off and make django return just error strings or json or something instead. Can someone help me get rid of this html?

Comment: I do not use django myself, so I'm unfamiliar with it. I just feel like it should be an option in django to have it not give error pages and instead give error strings with no html.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

This will let you configure the logging in your django project.

Comment: I'm not talking about errors from the API. I'm talking about when django itself has some error of why it couldn't even execute the API, it spits out a huge html block. We are handling errors from the APIs just fine.

Comment: Got it. In that case, checkout this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

Answer (score 0):

Your Django app is working in debug mode. Please try this. 
Go to ../yourdjangoproject/yourdjangoproject/settings.py 
and find line `Debug = True`. Making it `Debug=False` will stop it from spitting out huge html upon errors.

Another thing you can do to only see errors as nice api response strings is this:

Find the view function which is giving the error, which can be found through the same huge html error message or by checking the view for url in urls.py

Then surround the whole view in try except like this.

`def your_api_view(bla):
     try:
        #all of the view code goes here
     except Exception as e:
        return Response({"Error":e})`

This way the error message will be shown to you like normal api response string.

Comment: That makes it spit out nothing though doesn't it? It says setting debug to false just makes it give generic 500 errors, not that it makes it not give errors in html format.

Comment: Whenever your django web app is in error, it will not run, and display a short 500 page or a full debug page depending on Debug setting. So when u send api request to some api view and that view goes to error, the website will give u raw html if you are sending web request from something other then browser like requests library. If u want to see only tracebacks of errors, you should setup logging to a file. http://ianalexandr.com/blog/getting-started-with-django-logging-in-5-minutes.html this will get u started. And to avoid html spitting by django, plz make sure the views never go to error.

Comment: I am editing my answer with another option. Please try that as well.

Comment: We are only using django as the REST API. I just want it to realize it should never be dealing with html and stop showing me any html ever. I don't want to have to configure it for every case. Is there a way to do it for all of django?